# Plotly Choropleth in R - Too Many Requests (RFC 6585) (HTTP 429)

Tags: r, plotly, http-status-code-429

I am receiving the following error when running a script generating many (approx. 80) choropleths using [Plotly](https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/) in short time

```
Error in process.image(append_class(resp, "image")) : 
  Too Many Requests (RFC 6585) (HTTP 429).
```

Has anyone encountered this error before? I think it might be a response from their web server (e.g. some anti-DOS filter). Therefore I was thinking of adding some **execution pauses** in between the `plotly()`-calls, something like the following:

```
plot_ly(...)
Sys.sleep(5)
plot_ly(...)
...
```

Do you have any advice how I could bypass this error message?

Comment: please respect their rate limits: http://help.plot.ly/api-rate-limits/ since you're not a paying customer

Comment: @hrbrmstr, thank you, what a pity :-/

Comment: Agreed. It's sad folks aren't willing to pay for resources they rely on.

Comment: Do you want to make this the answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is (thanks to @hrbrmstr!) that Plotly uses **RATE LIMITS** (can be found here: http://help.plot.ly/api-rate-limits) based on user status (i.e. customer or non-customer).